# can't generate project with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am using Linux on windows (WSL).
When I try to scaffold a project with create-react-app I get this message:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/sashacode/.cache/yarn/v4/npm-table-5.2.3-cde0cc6eb06751c009efab27e8c820ca5b67b7f2/node_modules/table/README.md'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/mnt/c/Users/PC2/Apps/react_projects/new_world/yarn-error.log".
```

info Visit [link](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/) add for documentation about this command.

```
Aborting installation.
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /mnt/c/Users/PC2/Apps/react_projects/new_world has failed.
```

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.

Don't know what's going on. Any help?

Comment: After what command do you get this error?

Comment: Have you tried running `yarn cache clean`?

Comment: Please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) properly so as to clearly distinguish what's part of your question and what's part of the error log

Comment: Please describe exactly the commands you ran before receiving this error so that we can [reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Update node js to a newer version
then run `create-react-app` again
this should solve your problem